# 501 error while on https and wamp server

Tags: https, wamp

I added SSL to my WAMP server on local host. Everything is working fine when I request for http url but when I ask https url it returns me 501 Not implemented error message for all external included files ie. images/js/css files.

Any remedies.

I am using WAMP Server 2.4 latest version from website. and did SSL settings as per the URL http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,32986 ssl working but resources would load as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and fixed it.

For those who stuck with same issue.

One more major issue with Wamp 2.4 is that Resources ie. .css, .js and image files don't load even after all configuration. To solve the issue kindly do the following:

download and install 1.0.1e openssl from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

then find the files in the installed directory:

bin\openssl.cfg (replace with confg\openssl.cnf after renaming the .cfg file to .cnf)
bin\libeay32.dll
bin\ssleay32.dll
bin\openssl.exe

Stop the server and replace those files and enjoy!